Why can't the compiler deduce this function template type?
template <typename StaticStringType>
StaticStringType MyToString()
{
    std::string s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{


    MyToString();
    // NO INSTANCE OF FUNCTION TEMPLATE MATCHES THE ARGUMENT LIST
}

I've also tried:
template <typename StaticStringType>
auto MyToString() -> std::string


Template argument can't be deduced from return type. Maybe you can specify the default type like template <typename StaticStringType = std::string> ....

What are you hoping to accomplish?

What should StaticStringType be deduced to and why?

Because this is a non-deduced context i.e., there is no way for deduction to work here. See dupe: What is a non-deduced context and Template deduction for function based on its return type?

The compiler cannot deduce the template arguments because there's nothing deduction can be done on.
Template argument deduction is done on parameters sent to the function. No parameters, no deduction.
Maybe what your looking for is not template argument deduction, but I'll show it first anyway.
Here's an example of this function with template argument deduction, given through a parameter:
template <typename StaticStringType>
auto MyToString(StaticStringType value) -> StaticStringType
{
    std::string s;
    return value;
}

int main()
{

    int value;
    MyToString(value); // compiler deduces int, since `value` is of type int
}

If you simply want your function to return std::string instead, then no template parameter is needed:
auto MyToString() -> std::string
{
    std::string s;
    return value;
}

Or let the compiler deduce the return type. Simply leaving auto without trailing return type will make the compiler look for the return statement and deduce the return type from the expression:
auto MyToString() // return type deduced to be `-> std::string`
{
    std::string s;
    return value;
}


Hangon, I thought auto was syntactic sugar for the template, to the extent that auto MyToString() -> std::string { }was equivalent to template  T MyToString() { return std::string; }

@Zebrafish auto in parameters is equivalent to a template, auto in return types is just like auto in variables, the compiler works out what the type is from the code but it's not templated

If I have template  SomeType myfunc() { return SomeType();} I can't can't call it with myfunc(); However I can call auto myfunc() { return SomeType();} with just myfunc(), so auto template are completely different things? I understood that it was a syntactic sugar type of thing.

@Zebrafish Return type deduction is very different from templates. auto parameter is a syntactic sugar for templates, yes, but return type deduction also denoted by auto is not syntactic sugar for anything. Return type deduction is a feature on its own that allow compilers to deduce the return type of a function based on its body. It's indeed more similar to auto variable than templates.

You can use return type deduction, or you can use templates, or you can use both. Both feature are completely orthogonal and don't influence each other. Return type deduction cannot turn a function into a template, and templates cannot cause a function to have return type deduction.
